# what is hapenning with my foreach at the moment to insert data to db?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to insert my data in to my database when I try to added as my `product_id` is an `array` then show me an error like this , i need to add it one by one, but I want to add them altogether if I Have `2 , 3 , 4 , 10+ etc` etc , how can I iterate on my `foreach` in my `model` to add them?

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES('low stock', 'low stock', ('4170','4171'), 1, 1500579824)
```

**My Controller:**

```
<?php
    public function tests() {
        $array = $this->sale->get_all_cart($this->session->carrito);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $product_id[] = $value['id'];
        }
        $entryData = array(
            'message' => 'low stock',
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'type' => 'low stock',
            'timestamp' => time()
        );
        $this->notification->addNotification($entryData);
    }
?>
```

**My Model**

```
<?php
    function addNotification(Array $data) {
        $types = array(
            'new' => 0,
            'pending' => 1,
            'low stock' => 2
        );
        if (isset($types[$data['type']]) === false) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
        }
        $type                 = $types[$data['type']];
        $query                = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN ? AND type = ? ";
        $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array(
            $data['product_id'],
            $data['type']
        ))->result_array();
        if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] >= 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            try {
                /*foreach ($data as $value) {
                print_r($value['product_id']);
                }*/
                if (!$this->db->query($sql, array(
                    $data['message'],
                    $data['type'],
                    $data['product_id'],
                    $data['user_id'],
                    $data['timestamp']
                ))) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why is your product id two fields?

Comment: because is an array , i need to add it both or whatever if I Have 500 ids + then add it , how can I do the foreach to add it ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do it with for each.

Comment: how can I? i tried do it foreach $data['product_id'] and fails

Comment: this is my output from array from model low stockArray ( [0] => 4170 [1] => 4171 ) 1low stock1500580846  , i try this but fails foreach ($data as $value) {
                print_r($value['product_id']);
            }

Comment: You add addNotification into the loop will make more sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149750/discussion-between-fernando-osuna-and-ibu).